# automatic row spanning in css grid

Tags: css, css-grid

Is there a way to get automatic row spanning (item occupies automatic number of vertical grid cells)?

In my example, I'd like cell 8 to span 2 (or more) cells automatically, without having to explicitly say `span 2`. I've been looking high and low how to do this, but it doesn't seem possible.

I'd like to have each cell a multiple of, say 100px, so that the smallest cell is 100px, if the content overflows it becomes 200px tall, and with more content 300px, etc.

In other words I'm hoping there is a way the css grid can determine XX automatically:

```
.i {  grid-row: span XX; }
```

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(200px, 2fr));
  grid-auto-flow: dense;
}

.grid div {
  border-left: 1px solid #000;
  border-top: 1px solid #000;
  padding: 10px;
}

.grid div.i {
  grid-row: span 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
  <div>5</div>
  <div>6</div>
  <div>7</div>
  <div class="i">8aslkdj ljsa lkj dasljdks lajsld jlasdl sldjslda ld jla8aslkdj ljsa lkj dasljdks lajsld jlasdl sldjslda ld jla8aslkdj ljsa lkj dasljdks lajsld jlasdl sldjslda ld jla8aslkdj ljsa lkj dasljdks lajsld jlasdl sldjslda ld jla</div>
  <div>9</div>
  <div>10</div>
  <div>11</div>
  <div>12</div>
  <div>13</div>
  <div>14</div>
  <div>15</div>
  <div>16</div>
  <div>17</div>
</div>
```

https://codepen.io/joe_g/pen/VbLRpN

Answer (score 15, accepted):

No, this is not currently possible with CSS grid. You’ll have to continue use the `span` keyword.

You may have to use JavaScript to detect long content and dynamically add a class to the grid items that have more content.

Comment: I'm surprised they didn't include this functionality. You would have to be on top of the length of your content at all times, that limits the use of css grids, I think.

Comment: Grid is about imposing an alignment across multiple rows and/or columns. The size of one grid item is meant to influence the size of other elements on the grid so they remain aligned.

Flexbox is more suited to, well, flexing, based on the contents within. For the effect you are looking for, Flexbox might be a better fit.

Comment: That said, this is an interesting use-case, that sort of sits in the space between both grid & flexbox. It might be worth mentioning this on Rachel Andrew’s Grid AMA: https://github.com/rachelandrew/cssgrid-ama. She & the rest of the W3C are interested in hearing about use-cases the spec doesn’t yet address.

Comment: thanks, I did that: https://github.com/rachelandrew/cssgrid-ama/issues/80. And now its part of the discussion for the next version of css grid: https://github.com/w3c/csswg-drafts/issues/1373